# How to display the data on hover?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to display data on mouseover, however, I am weak in jQuery, and I don't know how to get the data through it on hover. This is my function so far:

```
function test_contact_group($id){
    $results = $this
        ->Contact
        ->ContactsContactGroup
        ->find('all', array('conditions'=> array('ContactsContactGroup.contact_id'=>$id,)));
    $this->set('results',$results); 
}
```

And my view is:

```
    <div class="firsttable">
    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2">
        <thead>
            <tr class="heading">
                <td><?php echo __l('Group Name');?></td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php foreach ($results as $results){?>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <?php echo $results['ContactGroup']['name']?>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <?php }?>
        </tbody>
    </table>    
</div>
```

and the link which will get the data is

```
  <?php echo $this->Manager->link($records['ContactGroup']['name'],array('action'=> 'test_contact_group', $records['Contact']['contact_id']));?>
```

HTML of the link is

```
  <a href="/contacts/test_contact_group/78">default</a>
```

i want to display the data through this link on hover, how can i do that, please help me to do that, any body can help it will appreciated, thanks in advance

the Param which i passed on link is

```
 $records['Contact']['contact_id'])
```

Comment: So why are you referencing a php function while asking for jQuery? You can't load a php function with javascript/jQuery

Comment: i just want to do simply brief in detail that what i want to try to do.

Comment: Which HTML element needs to be hovered? And where is your data that you like to display?

Comment: @s.lenders i have edit in the question now you can understand what i want to view

Comment: `This is my function so far` <- that is php, nothing anyone can do with in jQuery. Still you post me a html and php file but don't tell what element needs to be hovered to set of the event to show a unknown set of data. Again, what needs to be hovered, what needs to be shown, where does it need to be shown. Your question is not complete the only thing it says is you don't understand much of jQuery and that you have a function that is not done.

Comment: Go to your page, right-click, and select 'View source', then copy the rendered HTML. Javascript operates on the client-side HTML, not the server-side PHP, so we need to see that code to help you.

Comment: this is html of the link <a href="/contacts/test_contact_group/78">default</a>

Answer (score 0):

Since your question doesn't define specifics i'm going to provide you with jQuery libaries that can direct you to your question

There are several solutions, one is putting the data already into the html but hiding it with CSS. On hover you can toggle the visibility of that element. For this look into [Jquery Effects](http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/) which cover stuff like: show, hide, toggle, fadein, fadeout, fadetoggle etc.

If you are not looking for static loaded content and like to retrieve the information on hover then you should take a look into any of the [Jquery ajax](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/) features such as: Get, Post or Load